# Oracle SQL - Pivoting the columns with varying columns needed

Tags: oracle

I have the following data

```
Vehicle_ID       Date            Problem
 X500         01/01/2020      Engine Oil
 X500         01/01/2020        Brake
 X500         01/01/2020      Dynamic Brake
 X500         01/01/2020         RPM
 X500         01/02/2020      Dynamic Brake
 X500         01/02/2020         RPM
```

I need to Pivot the problem column so for each Vehicle_ID, Date we have one row.
But the problem is Count of Problem for each Vehicle_ID, Date varies from 2 - 30.

The expected output is

```
Vehicle_ID      Date       Problem_1     Problem_2     Problem_3    Problem_4      Problem_5     ....
  X500        01/01/2020   Engine Oil      Brake     Dynamic Brake     RPM           
  X500        01/01/2020   Dynamic Brake    RPM
```

I tried the basic pivot but it didn't work

```
Select * from table1
PIVOT(
       Problem
       FOR (Problem) IN (SELECT DISTINCT Probelm FROM table1)
     )
```

Comment: The problem requirement doesn't make a lot of sense. Why do you need the "problems" presented in individual columns, one problem per column? The resulting columns have no meaning. You might as well (making it easier to solve, as well as to use) show the problems per (vehicle, date) pair in a **single** column, separated by space or by (comma, space) like this: `Engine Oil, Brake, Dynamic Brake, RPM` and respectively `Dynamic Brake, RPM`. With that said: **Why** are you doing this? Who or what is going to consume (use) this output, and how?

Comment: This is for passing as features for my predictive models. Once I convert them, I would be able to pass them for predicting

Answer (score 0):

If you know there are up to 30 problems for a vehicle, you can generate that many columns.  I would use conditional aggregation:

```
select vehicle_id, date,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then problem end) as problem_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then problem end) as problem_2,
       . .  
       max(case when seqnum = 30 then problem end) as problem_30
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by vehicle_id, date order by problem) as seqnum
      from table1
     ) t1
group by vehicle_id, date
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that there are not more than 30 rows per vehicle per date then you can use the `PIVOT` as follows:

```
select *
from (select vehicle_id, date, problem,
             row_number() over (partition by vehicle_id, date order by problem) as rn
      from your_table
     ) 
pivot (max(problem) for rn in (1,2,3,4,...., 29,30))
```